# Error Handling in React Components in REACT 16

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn error handling in react. The application is live [here](https://atyagi4-shoppingcart.herokuapp.com/) and GitHub code is [this](https://github.com/phoenix010/Shopping-Cart-App/tree/master/src).
I am trying to get a fallback UI when error rises in Navbar`(navbar.jsx`) the way which is mentioned in React documentation, but, I am not able to implement it the way I want to. In App.js, when I render only one `return()` and get navbar component into `errorBoundary`, I am not getting the required fallback UI.

App.JS

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Counters from "./components/counters";
import "./App.css";
import ErrorBoundary from "./components/ErrorBoundary";
const lodash = require("lodash");
let uniqid = require("uniqid");
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: uniqid(), value: 0 },
      { id: uniqid(), value: 0 },
      { id: uniqid(), value: 0 },
      { id: uniqid(), value: 0 }
    ]
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initialCounters = lodash.cloneDeep(this.state.counters);
  }
  handleDefault = () => {
    const counters = this.initialCounters;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleIncrement = counter => {
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  handleAddition = counter => {
    // console.log("Adding new components");
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    console.log(counters);
    // console.log("The old length is: ", counters.length);
    const index = counters.length;
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    // console.log("The new length is: ", counters.length);
    counters[index].value = 0;
    counters[index].id = uniqid();
    // console.log("The ID is", counters[index].id);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  handleDelete = counterId => {
    console.log("Event Handler Called", counterId);
    const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId);
    this.setState({ counters });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters });
  };
  render() {
    if (this.state.counters.length === 0) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h1>All Items have been deleted.</h1>
          <p>Click on default to get back to default state</p>
          <button
            onClick={this.handleDefault}
            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm m-2"
          >
            Default
          </button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <NavBar
            totalValues={this.state.counters
              .map(c => c.value)
              .reduce(function(acc, curr) {
                return acc + curr;
              })}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Counters
            counters={this.state.counters}
            onDefault={this.handleDefault}
            onReset={this.handleReset}
            onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            onAdd={this.handleAddition}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className=" navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
            "Total Number of Items: "{this.props.totalValues}
          </span>
        </a>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

ErrorBoundary.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasError: false
    };
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }
  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    // logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: What would cause `NavBar` to throw an error? Do you get your `<h1>` if you force an error, e.g. by adding `throw Error("test")` inside the NavBar's `render` function?

Comment: Navbar will throw an error when you delete all the components. When you delete all the components, the length of the array gets zero, and you cant reduce an array of size zero. Therefore, the Navbar component will throw an error.

Comment: `NavBar` doesn't reduce anything though, `App` does that when it calculates the `totalValues` prop to pass to `NavBar`. Since `App` is not within your `ErrorBoundary` component, that won't render your custom UI.

Comment: Thank You, I got to know what is going wrong. Thank You